# what way to choose for storing documents and images on the server securely?

Tags: security, store

I'd like to ask you for your opinion how to store images and PDF's securely on a server. I'm using PHP to build the project and I was thinking about 2 options:

- to store the files in a protected directory by an .htaccess (Deny from all)
- to store the images and PDF in MySQL (don't know how exactly) in some encrypted binary fashion, but don't know if this is efficient enough

Any suggestions, folks? :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first solution is the easiest/quickest.

Your second one allows encryption as a binary file can be stored into a blob. Imagine you are storing a large piece of text. To load the image back, just add the image type header in the response.

It really depends on your security needs.

Comment: thanks, I was wondering however if it will hurt performanece .... as I read in mupltiple places, that the recommended way is only to store file references in DB and actual files in the filesystem

Comment: It does affect performances. But if you store your files in the filesystem, you will still need a protection (like .htaccess or filters) ; as your folders might be crawled.

Comment: is the aforementioned by me .htaccess Deny from all gonna do the job?

Comment: Yes, use also a htpassword file to have at least one person access your docs

Answer (score 0):

Determine how secure should it be. What is attack scenario? Could attacker take over your web-service, apache, your system?

First solution sounds most appropriate for common situations. The second one is too complex to works really well. (what about keys? and so on...)